# Why doesn't this user have the association bonus?

Tags: discussion, reputation, linked-accounts, association, association-bonus

I've been browsing the stack exchange accounts and I don't how I reached [this account](https://stackexchange.com/users/1442735/battle-of-karbala?tab=accounts).
I'm very surprised why he has only 12 rep on this site:https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1757/battle-of-karbala

I have checked his reputation tab and it should be awarded:[image: reputation]

As you see the association bonus was awarded but there is nothing that shows that he lost 100 points.

Now I know that the reputation tab summarizes everything but I have to assure two points:

1. The user has a 10k reputation on one of the sites, so he should earn the association bonus.
2. The user has not offered any bounties on this site.
3. I have checked that this isn't a problem with my browser

Comment: Maybe he posted spam, that's -100 penalty and not shown in the public reputation history. Another option is bounty of 100 on a question that was deleted after bounty was already awarded, such bounty also won't show publicly in his profile. Only a moderator on that site can tell for sure so better post this on the per-site meta. :)

Comment: I'm not that interested in that user himself, I wanted to get some information about such situations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Only assumptions in my comment above, there is always chance for a bug, hence we need a mod.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, was just thinking the same, although could it also be the order they joined sites? A few are pretty close together so also possibly joined before getting 200 on another site.

Comment: @PeterJ nope, order doesn't matter. When reaching 200 in one site, job/script is running and updating all associated accounts. (if the user have such accounts)